# MGS Peace Walker boss: Peace Walker Type II

Tags: metal-gear-solid-peace-walker

This is a mission that comes after finishing the game and some extra ops. I'm having trouble defeating it, there aren't enough supply markers available! I used up all 10 supply markers and the boss still had half its life. What do I do?

Comment: How is this a spoiler? It's a given you'll fight Peace Walker in the end.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gamefaqs.com/psp/960566-metal-gear-solid-peace-walker/answers?qid=200180 has some suggestions that you might want to try.

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on the vital areas of Peace Walker (Such as the AI Pod) and focus on hitting it, only use your supply markers when you ABSOLUTELY need them (when you truly run out of ammo), and try using the strike marker as well. Make sure you're using the thrown version of the two instead of the pistols, as that takes up weapon space.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly don t have enougt ammo, just boost your base and wait for Carl Gustav and RPG7 rank 3, and try to get a M60(AP) or G3(AP).

Equip:

```
Battle Dress
M60/G3 (AP/SB)
Carl Gustav
RPG7
Supply Marker

All you can eat, and Mate
```

Shoot the AI Pod only, your damage will be tremendously faster on it than any other part.

When Peace Walker say "EM Pulse maximum", switch to the M60/G3, and continue to fire.

When it enter "Nuclear Lauch Sequence", fire every rocket you have on the missile launcher so it abandon faster.

Do not use supply marker before you have emptied all your ammo.

Be careful, Peace Walker Type II is a strong step harder than Cocoon Type II, you should not be ashamed of doing the other Extra Ops and recruiting before attacking it.